# Can landscape adhesive be used for a masonry fire pit?

Tags: fireplace, adhesive, pavers

I'm building a fire pit...Just like in [this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2scP.png).

[image: Can la]

At 1:40 he is using an adhesive (looks like versa-lok concrete adhesive).  I didn't think it was needed, but I like the idea.  I thought video would use it on the base, but they use it only on the courses.

I didn't see anything about high heat in on the tub.

Is it effective under heat?

Can something like this give off dangerous fumes when heated?

Comment: I'm not sure what you consider the "base" vs the "course", but he says "_every_ brick in _every_ course" which I would take to include the base course that's sitting directly on the patio pavers. Also, he's _waaay_ to excited about this whole thing... _shudder_. Have you checked out multiple versions of masonry adhesive to see if any indicate heat resistance? Frankly, I'd doubt that the adhesive will get all that hot.

Comment: What do the instructions say in your kit?

Comment: If you are worried about it then use a refractory cement, Made for high heat applications. I would not cement the bottom course to the patio in case you ever want to remove it, all the courses cemented together will be  heavy enough to keep it from moving. Make sure your patio pavers (*the base you putting it on*)  are the thick ones like in video, and not thin ones that will crack.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a free-standing fire pit of similar pavers on soil and  haven't bothered bonding them. They haven't gone anywhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I talked to a sales person at a hardscape place.

He gave me:

Loctite PL 500 landscape

EDIT:
I used the PL 500 Landscape adhesive towards the outside and it's solid.
[image: Completed fire pt]

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Loctite PL 500 landscape adhesive (mentioned in [the asker's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/203979/35141))...

> [Service Temperature: -20°F (-29°C) to 150°F (66°C)](https://dm.henkel-dam.com/is/content/henkel/T4EX6MEpdf)

No, landscape adhesive (or at least that specific product) isn't rated for temperatures encountered in a fire pit.

That said, if you put a bead toward the outside of the course rings I'd expect it to hold up fairly well. Temperatures out there may get high enough to soften it, but probably wouldn't burn it.

Of course, there may be landscape adhesives (or products that could serve as such) with higher temperature tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a [fireplace mortar](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/heating-and-cooling/chimney-and-flue/chimney-brushes-and-accessories/40463?store=14594&gclid=CjwKCAjwwab7BRBAEiwAapqpTHZzZmlce7thRwXwBJcys3ohWC9p5u2TJHwjtLlBWkl8hw0G2ntDTRoCbq8QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) (like this example from Ace Hardware).

For flatter bricks I have used this [furnace cement](https://www.grainger.com/product/39AT59?gclid=CjwKCAjwwab7BRBAEiwAapqpTNVNuesGkR3Bd8NwsXl_aNXmdSXuqPnc62L2I_3x_E1fXFMU1dPW3BoCz-gQAvD_BwE&cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=CjwKCAjwwab7BRBAEiwAapqpTNVNuesGkR3Bd8NwsXl_aNXmdSXuqPnc62L2I_3x_E1fXFMU1dPW3BoCz-gQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!264922886859!!!g!438649192311!&gucid=N:N:PS:Paid:GGL:CSM-2293:RMFWPG:20500731) (sold by Grainger, among others).

I have made a lot of fire pits.   I would go with the first one - or any type like that (the link was not a recommendation just example).   Note that I have used pavers almost exactly like yours with about the same size pit, maybe a tad bigger.   Note that some of them cracked when we made some extremely hot fires involving large oak logs.